# Run play application in dev mode in docker

Tags: docker, playframework, sbt

I want to use docker during developing. It's comfortable. But play application shutdown after start in dev mode.

I have docker-compose for play framework and postgres.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: db
      POSTGRES_USER: user_role
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
    volumes:
    - ${HOME}/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - my-net
  scala-back:
    container_name: scala-back
    image: hseeberger/scala-sbt
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    - ivy:/root/.ivy2
    - type: bind
      source: .
      target: /app
    command: /bin/bash -c 'cd /app && sbt run'
    ports:
      - "80:9000"
    networks:
      - my-net
networks:
  my-net:
    name: my-net
volumes:
  ivy:
```

After `docker-compose up` i have been getting

```
scala-back    | --- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---
scala-back    | 
scala-back    | [info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000
scala-back    | 
scala-back    | (Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)
scala-back    | 
scala-back    | [info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Stopping server...
scala-back    | [info] p.a.h.EnabledFilters - Enabled Filters (see <https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Filters>):
scala-back    | 
scala-back    |     play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter
scala-back    |     play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter
scala-back    |     play.filters.cors.CORSFilter
scala-back    | 
scala-back    | [info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
scala-back    | 
scala-back    | [success] Total time: 6 s, completed May 6, 2019 7:00:37 PM
scala-back    | [INFO] [05/06/2019 19:00:37.223] [Thread-3] [CoordinatedShutdown(akka://sbt-web)] Starting coordinated shutdown from JVM shutdown hook
scala-back exited with code 0
```

I tried `screen -d -m sbt run` in command, but this is didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start your containers with `docker-compose up -d`. With the option `-d` your containers get started in detached mode and your application should not be stopped.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Jack, i don't close terminal after `docker-compose up`, but i have tried what you suggested. And `docker logs scala-back` returns the same output, but without `scala-back exited with code 0`. But application still stopping.

Comment: Can you try to add the option `tty: true` and/or `stdin_open: true` to your scala-back container? This means that it keeps a terminal attached and a console connection